# Two-outcome dotplot by panel variable over several models (lattice dotplot in R)

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to produce a dotplot over two variables (matched, unmatched) over several categories as below.  The following code roughly does what I want (using dummy data):

```
library(lattice)

# Generate dummy data that resembles my real data
dp0 <- data.frame(expand.grid(covariate=c("var1","var2"), semester=1:5,
                              treatment=LETTERS[1:3]), matched=runif(30),
                              unmatched=runif(30))

# Plot matched and unmatched (percentages) by several semester-level covariates
# across several treatments (models):
dotplot(semester ~ matched + unmatched | treatment + covariate, data=dp0)
```

It produces the following:

[image: Two-outcome dotplot by covariate-semester over treatment]

Column labels A, B, and C are all just fine (not necessary to be replicated across rows nor with horrid peach color, but acceptable as is), but row labels (var2, var1) are intended to be less important than column labels.  I envision something that looks like this:

```
       |    A    |    B    |    C    |
var1:  |                             |
.... 1 | x  o    |   o   x |  ox     |
.... 2 |   ox    | x  o    |  o    x |
.... 3 |o     x  |     o  x| x o     |
.... 4 | x     o | x o     |  o  x   |
.... 5 |   o x   |     x o |    ox   |
       |         |         |         |
var2:...
```

I tried to mess with group, for instance, but that does not help.  This graph is correct as given only it is misleading in the manner it is displayed (in other words, this is a display issue, not a data issue).  What are the concepts I should be searching for to accomplish this?  Any thoughts appreciated.

Final graph based on @JPC's answer:

```
ma <- c("Unmatched", "Matched")
ma <- factor(ma, levels=ma, ordered=TRUE)
ggplot(dp0, aes(y=semester)) + geom_point(aes(x=unmatched, shape=ma[1], color=ma[1])) +
    geom_point(aes(x=matched, shape=ma[2], color=ma[2])) + facet_grid(covariate~treatment) +
    xlim(-1, 1) + labs(x=NULL,y=NULL) + scale_shape_discrete(name="") +
    scale_colour_discrete(name="", guide="legend") + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image: Final Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rjturn, I realized you're trying to do this with lattice, but figured I'd share the ggplot2 version. I find ggplot2 do be more beautiful and simpler to understand since there is an underlying logic of layers.

```
qplot(x=matched+unmatched, y=semester,data=dp0)+facet_grid(covariate~treatment)
```

[image]

You might also want to look into the `reshape` library, it is very useful in combination with `ggplot2`. See below for a simplification of your graphing code.

```
library(reshape2)
flatdp0<-melt(data=dp0,id=c("covariate","semester","treatment"))

qplot(data=flatdp0,x=value, y=semester,color=variable, shape=variable)+
  facet_grid(covariate ~ treatment)+labs(color="",shape="",x="",y="")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]

Comment: This was just the right impetus to finally go and learn ggplot2.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I worked with lattice a bit a while back, and have found ggplot2 did everything I needed in a simpler, more consistent way.

Comment: I note for future viewers that this answer adds each x coordinate, x=matched+unmatched.  To get two dots on each line, one must specify each x-coordinate inside a geom_point(aes(x=VAR_X1)) call as above (the y-coordinate may be specified in the base ggplot(y=VAR_Y) call since the y value does not change between the two values of X (that is, we _want_ the two X's to appear on the same line)

Comment: woopsie! sorry completely missed that part of your specification, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a late answer, it may help those still using `lattice` and it addresses the fact that `qplot()` in the accepted answer is now deprecated to *encourage the users to learn `ggplot()` as it makes it easier to create complex graphics*. I found that `ggplot` then `ggplot2` evolved more frequently than I wished. I use it for some tasks but after investing the time to learn `trellis` and then `lattice`, I find that `lattice` remains rather useful. Also, more recent versions of `lattice` use a more subdued color scheme than the 'horrid peach' color!

```
  library(latticeExtra) # need this support package
  obj <- dotplot(semester ~ matched + unmatched | treatment + covariate, dp0,
    scales = list(x = list(alternating = FALSE, tck = c(0.5, 0), rot = 90)))
  useOuterStrips(obj)
```

[image: useOuterStrips solution]